# From R to scala: Importing Libraries

Tags: r, scala, apache-spark, import, libraries

I came from R and I am trying to use scala to explore the possibilities to do data science. I don't have any background in programming or computer science, my background is pretty much statistical. So far I am only using scala from the REPL, which I like because it reminds my of the R console.

I am encountering problems when I am trying to import new libraries. In R, within the R console, I would just type

```
library(tidyverse)
```

In scala I am trying to do something similar, however it doesn't really work. Here what I see:

```
Welcome to Scala 2.12.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_172).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.vectors
<console>:11: error: object apache is not a member of package org
       import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.vectors
              ^
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Could you please try this : import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still get the same error 
`scala> import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

<console>:11: error: object apache is not a member of package org

       import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors`

Comment: It is working fine for me. I think you need to update your spark version.

Comment: Hi, I don't know if I have a Spark version, I do I check/install that? thank you

Comment: you need to install spark to use it

Comment: you can install spark following sparklyr instructions in your system. Then same local spark instance will be available from inside R/Rstudio or scala.

Comment: How can I do that? in R i would use the command `install.package("package name")` is there something similar in the scala REPL?

Answer (score 2):

Apache Spark is not a simple package that you can import from the standard Scala library, but rather somewhat of an ecosystem on its own, consisting of JARs with Java/Scala API's, cluster managers, distributed file systems, various launcher scripts and interactive shells (for Scala, but e.g. also for Python).
It's not a single interactive script that you run on your computer. It's rather a complex conglomerate of cooperating programs running on a cluster.

You have several options:

1. Use SBT: declare spark as a dependency in `build.sbt`, run it in standalone-mode from the SBT console or as properly built project, with `run`
2. Essentially same as `1.`, but use Ammonite with `$ivy` imports for managing dependencies.
3. Just go to the Spark website and follow installation instructions there. Among many other things, it should sooner or later give you a script that starts an interactive Scala REPL with all the dependencies that are needed to run Spark jobs.

I'd suggest to go right to step `3.` and [download Spark from here](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html).